# Python code doesn't run with [input]

Tags: python, raw-input

I am a complete noob in python and in programming, so I'm sure this question it may irritate some, so I am reading this book   which has this example which it does not run with out `raw_input`

```
#!/usr/bin/python
# -*- coding: utf-8 -*-
# Filename: continue.py
#!/usr/bin/python
# Filename: break.py
while True:
s = (raw_input('Enter something : '))
if s == 'quit':
break
print('Length of the string is', len(s))
print('Done')
```

What I mean is that when I add just `input` like in the book the code doesn't run. Why is that?

Comment: What do you mean *"add just `input`"*? Where? Which version of Python (3.x or 2.x)? Is that the indentation you're really trying to use?

Comment: whats your python version ? `input()` is for python 3.x...  run this command `python --version` on terminal ! also you have bad indentation !!!

Answer (score 1):

If the book is using Python 2.x, only raw_input will work. If you are using Python 3.x using input() will be fine.

Answer (score 1):

In python indentation is very important, it defines code blocks (indentation replaces { and } in many others languages like c/c++/java/etc...)

Try to re-indent your code correctly.

This code runs fine :

```
while True:
    s = (raw_input('Enter something : '))
    if s == 'quit':
        break
print('Length of the string is', len(s))
print('Done')
```

Another note :  don't run your code directly from a text editor (like sublime text) because raw_input is often captured by the text editor.